# Azure Recovery Services agent on Server Core 2016

Tags: windows, azure, backup, windows-server-2016

I'm attempting to install the Azure Recovery Services Agent on a 2016 Standard Server Core machine. It installs fine, but when I try to browse to the vault credential file, I get an exception that appears to be related to visual themes not existing since it's server core:
[image]

I've also tried setting up Azure Powershell to do backups through there, but when I try to login I get an error related to IEFrame.dll:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.WindowsFormsWebAuthenticationDialogBase' threw an exception.: Unable to load DLL 'IEFRAME.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

When I run Login-AzureRmAccount on a Desktop Experience server, it pops up a window to login, which apparently uses IE. I've also tried Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile, which works, but it still needs me to run Login-AzureRmAccount after running that.

Does anyone know of a command-line way to set the vault credentials for the Recovery Services agent? Or how to login in Powershell without IE?

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I'm trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: The "fix" recommended is to step an Azure Backup Server, which can then deploy the agents. It then gives you a central place to manage all of your servers that are backed up to Azure.

Comment: hm. I actually have an Azure backup server already. I was trying to switch from "backups" to "site recovery".  I'm stuck trying to set the VaultCredential file.

Comment: and for whatever reason I can't push the agent from the backup server anyway. it just fails. maybe a firewall issue or missing component in server core.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think the Azure team has no idea what Server Core is. I tried the File Sync client yesterday, and it requires IE for the initial login (the first step in the setup is turning off IE Enhanced Security). It's infuriating.

Comment: I tried following this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-powershell-support-for-azure-site-recovery/ but there is no Import-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile. There is a Import-AzureRmSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile but I don't know what the Rm is and it will not accept my VaultCredentials file.

Comment: or at least I can't find Import-AzureSiteRecoveryVaultSettingsFile

Answer (score 0):

[Download the latest PowerShell release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases) (minimum version required is: 1.0.0) and then Verify you have Windows PowerShell version 3.0 or 4.0. To find the version of Windows PowerShell, type this command at a Windows PowerShell command prompt.

$PSVersionTable

Verify that the value of PSVersion is 3.0 or 4.0. If not, see [Windows Management Framework 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=34595) or [Windows Management Framework 4.0.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=40855)

And then you can install Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent through [PowerShell command lets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-client-automation) on windows server 2016.

Comment: Azure Powershell is already installed. This doesn't answer my question at all